# Apply hidden attribute to span

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to mimic the way this element is hidden... it doesn't appear there is any css that is applied to the spans to make them hidden:

`<span hidden>E</span>`

I tried:

```
var letter = document.createElement('span');
letter.innerHTML = message.split("")[i];
letter.style.display = 'none';
```

But this does:

```
<span style="display: none;">E</span>
```

The `spans` are bare, meaning they don't have any class names associated with them. Meaning, they appear as such:

```
<span hidden>x</span>
<span hidden>y</span>
<span hidden>z</span>
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var letter = document.createElement('span');
letter.innerHTML = message.split("")[i];
letter.setAttribute("hidden","");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
letter.setAttribute("style", "display:none");
```

or:

```
letter.style.cssText = "display:none";
```

or you could set a class on your element and use this to hide the span:

```
letter.className = "hide";

.hide{
  display:none;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Funny. On modern browsers, setting the hidden attribute should do it on its own. It’s possible there is some CSS that is overriding the browser default display property. You can try adding this to fix it.

```
*[hidden] { display: none !important; }
```

NOTE: It should be *extremely* rare for you to use the “!important” tag on CSS. Since this is fixing browser default functionality, I consider it a valid use scenario.

Comment: `using it can come with some risks` what risks?

Comment: @Sinjai So back when I wrote this comment, I was not aware there was now a W3C Standard “Hidden” attribute. You can use that, plus the above trick, as needed. I’ve edited my original post.

Comment: Gotcha, figured it was just outdated. Thanks for the edit.